# Does a timed out HTTP POST result in SQL rollback?

Tags: mysql, http

From a question I asked previously ([Preventing duplicate INSERTS MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24303309/preventing-duplicate-inserts-mysql/24303593)) another question arose:

If a client delivers a POST request to a server, the server handles the POST, inserts into SQL and what not, then sends a reply (or at least HTTP 200 OK), but that reply is not received by the client... does the SQL statement then "not count" or does it auto-rollback or something?

This is very fundamental to using INSERT in POSTS for rows that cannot be uniquely identified by the client making the POST.

Comment: Can you explain _reply is not received_? What else is recieved? Also `HTTP 200 OK` mean the request is succeeded but it doesn't mean that your code actually fully/successfuly run.

Comment: This has nothing to do with what I asked, actually.

When I say "but that reply is not received by the client" I mean:

Client sends to server - received.
Server answers client request - not received by client.

In that scenario, would the server still perform the SQL statement or does the TCP protocol prevent this in some way?

Comment: The TCP protocol (or HTTP for that matter) is too low level to care anything about MySQL, rolling back, or anything. The behavior is dependent on the implementation at the application level, e.g. Apache and PHP. Provide more details to get a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, no, the server will not roll back the sql insert. The request was handled on the server side, and then completed.

Think of the server handling it like entering a function. Once the functions job is complete, it returns whatever need be (in this case, the response to the client), and then is done with. The same process happens here, the server does not wait to see whether or not the client has received the request as it's function has already been completed.

Comment: Thanks. That's all I needed to hear and also what I thought to be the truth.

Comment: Anytime, glad I could help you out! Feel free to upvote my response in order to keep it up in case others have the same question!